# Making GridView Visible

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a simple popup in windows 10 universal application. I've made a GridView

```
<GridView x:Name="PopUp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="453" Margin="10,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBox x:Name="Teacher" Height="29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Teacher's name" Width="330"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Room" Height="29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Room" Width="330"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Time" Height="29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Time" Width="330"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Subject" Height="29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Subject" Width="330"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="Day" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel"  Label="" Height="51" Margin="80,0,0,0"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="" Height="48" Margin="-40,-70,0,0" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </GridView>
```

I've got button "Add". I want my GridView become visible when User presses the add button, than he feels fields in GridView, presses "Ok" and GridView becomes invisible again. I used the buttonclick event, but it doesn't work:

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Popup pop = new Popup();
            pop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Maybe there is another way to create a popup(or I don't know how it's called) menu, because I don't want to create separate page for adding data.

Comment: Serkan's solution will work for you. Your code created a new instance of Popup which cannot show the one you named "PopUp" in xaml. directly set the visibility of "PopUp" should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        PopUp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

I hope This Help you let me know if its ok ;)